# Necessary & Sufficient Conditions for a set to be connected

Tags: general-topology

This question is based on Proposition 1.4.13 in Basic Complex Analysis, by Marsden.

> Definition 1.4.12: A set $C \subset \mathbb{C}$ is **not connected** if there exists open sets $U$ and $V$ such that, a) $\, C \subset U \cup V$, b) $\, C \cap U \not = \emptyset$ and $\, C \cap V \not = \emptyset$, c) $(C \cap U) \cap (C \cap V) = \emptyset$.
> If a set fails to be not-connected, then it's called **connected**.

> Proposition 1.4.13: A set $C$ is connected iff the only subsets of $C$ that are both open and closed relative to $C$ are the empty set and $C$ itself.

I'm trying to prove this using proof by contradiction for both directions,

$\Rightarrow (PBC):$ If $\exists C^*$ such that $C^* \subset C$ (strict) & $C^*$ is both open & closed relative to $C$, then $C \subset C^* \cup V^*$ where $V^* = \mathbb{C} \backslash C^*$ is open and properties b) & c) hold, a contradiction. $\Leftarrow (PBC):$ If $\exists U,V$ which satisfy the conditions above. Then, $U \cap C$ is open relative to $C$ by $b)$ and $U \cap C$ is closed relative to $C$ by.. ?

I'm struggling to derive a contradiction in the last direction, in Munkres (topology) the author states *U is non-empty and different from X and it's both open and closed in X*. However, I don't understand why we can say it's closed??

Thanks in advance

Take care!

:)

Comment: I think there are a few spots here where there's some trouble with relative topologies. The the $\Rightarrow$ direction, it should be that $C^*$ is open relative to $C$ and closed relative to $C$, not that $C^*$ is open and closed. 

For the second part, we don't say $U$ is open relative to $C$. $U\cap C$ is open relative to $C$. Then $U\cap C$ is closed relative to $C$ precisely because its complement relative to $C$ (which is $C\cap V$) is open relative to $C$.

Comment: Thank you! I have addressed these typos in the problem statement, one last thing, how can we show that the complement of $ U \cap C$ relative to $C$ equals $C \cap V$? I've tried to evaluate $C \backslash (U \cap C) = ... = (C \cap U^c) \cup (C \cap V^c)$, but am unsure how to make the connection, am i missing something super simple, thanks in advance,

Comment: By $a$, $$C=C\cap (U\cup V)=(C\cap U)\cup (C\cup V).$$ By $c$, $$(C\cap U)\cap (C\cap V)=\varnothing,$$ so $C\cap U$, $C\cap V$ partition $C$.

Comment: This helped me greatly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $C$ is not connected. Then there exist $U, V$, both open in $\mathbb{C}$, such that: (1) neither $C \cap U$ nor $C \cap V$ is empty, (2) $C \subseteq U \cup V$, and (3) $(C \cap U) \cap (C \cap V) = \emptyset$.

We claim that the set $C \cap U$ is both open and closed, relative to $C$.

It is trivial that $C \cap U$ is open relative to $C$, since $U$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$.

To see that $C \cap U$ is closed relative to $C$, it is enough to show that $C - (C \cap U)$ is open relative to $C$. First, we have that $C - (C \cap U) = C \cap (\mathbb{C} - U)$. We now show that $C \cap (\mathbb{C} - U) = C \cap V$, completing the proof.

Take $z \in C \cap (\mathbb{C} - U)$. Clearly, $z \in C$. From (2) above, this implies $z \in U$ or $z \in V$. But $z \notin U$, so it must be that $z \in V$. This shows $z \in C \cap V$.

Now take $w \in C \cap V$; in other words, $w \in C$ and $w \in V$. Suppose that further $w \in U$. Then $(C \cap U) \cap (C \cap V) = C \cap U \cap V$ contains $w$, which contradicts (3) above. So we must have that $w \notin U$, or $w \in \mathbb{C} - U$. This shows $w \in C \cap (\mathbb{C} - U)$.

Answer (score 0):

We claim $C$ is not connected if and only if there exist relatively open non-empty $U', V' \subset C$ such that $U' \cup V = C$ and $U' \cap V' = \emptyset$.

Given $U, V$ as in the definition, simply take $U' = U \cap C$ and $V' = V \cap C$. Conversely, given $U', V'$ as above, there exist open $U, V \subset \mathbb C$ such that $U' = U \cap C$ and $V' = V \cap C$. These sets have the properties required in the definition.

The Proposition is equivalent to the following statement:

> A set $C$ is not connected iff there exists a subset $W \subset C$ with $W \ne \emptyset, C$ which is both open and closed relative to $C$.

Given such $W$, the sets $U' = W, V' = C \setminus W$ have the properties in the above claim. Conversely, given $U', V'$ with these properties, take $W = U'$.